# how can i link to vue's build folder(dist) from window.open() function?

Tags: vue.js, asp-classic

I'm using ASP classic and middle of changing into vue.js.

but the problem is i need to use BOTH.

what i want is,

when i click image in asp, i want new window open with vue build project.

[this is what i see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fpul.png)

i'm using IIS,

i made new website using dist folder only with vue.js, it works.(with rewrite URL in IIS)

but when i tried to combine asp and vue dist directory, it doesn't fetch the resources.

```
//asp code
window.open("/dist/index.html" ,"asp","toolbar=no,resizable=yes,directories=no,status=no,left=0,top=0,height="+scrheight+",width=1010");
```

Comment: Welcome to SO @sora. This may be to do with the relative location of your folders. Are you sure that `/dist/index.html` can be reached from the ASP page's location?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Mike! 
I solved the problem by checking the locations of resources.
yes, i checked /dist/index.html location and it was in right location. but the problem was the other sources'es location. when you look at the 'index.html', js and css were built from the root. so i needed to change as '/dist/xxxx.css' and '/dist/xxx.js'. 
i changed this and it worked!